# How to convert sql query into pyspark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have sql query but when I am running that I am getting error. May be syntax is not same in pyspark sql. Could you please help me?

SQL Query:

```
WITH cte1 AS (select `Project Number` from vw_onco_pharma onco_pharma union all select `Project Number` from vw_onco_cell_gene cell_gene union all select `Project Number` from vw_non_onco_cell_gene onco_cell_gene union all select `Project Number` from vw_non_onco_pharma non_onco_pharma union all select `Project Number` from vw_plasma_protein plasma_protein),
cte2 AS (SELECT `Project Number`, COUNT(*) cnt FROM cte1 GROUP BY `Project Number`), cte3 AS (select `Project Number`, COUNT(*) cnt from vw_FCT_HTA_ONC_NONONC_PGMS GROUP BY `Project Number`), cte4 AS (SELECT `Project Number` FROM cte1 UNION  SELECT `Project Number` FROM cte3) SELECT `Project Number` FROM cte4 LEFT JOIN cte2 USING (`Project Number`) LEFT JOIN cte4 USING (`Project Number`) WHERE cte2.cnt IS NULL OR cte4.cnt IS NULL OR cte2.cnt <> cte4.cnt;
```

Pyspark I did-

```
>>> df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '|').options(header='true', escape='\"', inferSchema='false').load('/app/HTA/Intermediate/onco_pharma/onco_pharma_active.txt')
>>> df_read_file.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_onco_pharma')
21/10/12 05:05:06 WARN package: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields'.
>>> df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '|').options(header='true', escape='\"', inferSchema='false').load('/app/HTA/Intermediate/non_onco_pharma/non_onco_pharma_active.txt')
>>> df_read_file.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_non_onco_pharma')
>>> df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '|').options(header='true', escape='\"', inferSchema='false').load('/app/HTA/Intermediate/onco_cell_gene/onco_cell_gene_active.txt')
>>> df_read_file.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_onco_cell_gene')
>>> df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '|').options(header='true', escape='\"', inferSchema='false').load('/app/HTA/Intermediate/non_onco_cell_gene/non_onco_cell_gene_active.txt')
>>> df_read_file.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_non_onco_cell_gene')
>>> df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '|').options(header='true', escape='\"', inferSchema='false').load('/app/HTA/Intermediate/plasma_protein/plasma_protein_active.txt')
>>> df_read_file.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_plasma_protein')
>>>
>>> df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '|').options(header='true', escape='\"', inferSchema='false').load('/app/HTA/Consumption/FCT_HTA_ONC_NONONC_PGMS/FCT_HTA_ONC_NONONC_PGMS.txt')
>>> df_read_file.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_FCT_HTA_ONC_NONONC_PGMS')
```

Now I am trying to run query I am getting error.

```
>>> spark.sql('WITH cte1 AS (select `Project Number` from vw_onco_pharma onco_pharma union all select `Project Number` from vw_onco_cell_gene cell_gene union all select `Project Number` from vw_non_onco_cell_gene onco_cell_gene union all select `Project Number` from vw_non_onco_pharma non_onco_pharma union all select `Project Number` from vw_plasma_protein plasma_protein),
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    spark.sql('WITH cte1 AS (select `Project Number` from vw_onco_pharma onco_pharma union all select `Project Number` from vw_onco_cell_gene cell_gene union all select `Project Number` from vw_non_onco_cell_gene onco_cell_gene union all select `Project Number` from vw_non_onco_pharma non_onco_pharma union all select `Project Number` from vw_plasma_protein plasma_protein),
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: It looks you're entering a multi line sql string, try using triple quotes around your query instead, e.g. `'''SELECT * FROM ... '''`

Answer (score 0):

as ScootCork said, you are probably doing a line return within a simple quote string.

the best way to check that is to create a variable `sql` that will contains the sql you need and then, execute it in spark :

```py
sql_query = """WITH cte1 AS (select 'Project Number' from vw_onco_pharma onco_pharma union all select 'Project Number' from vw_onco_cell_gene cell_gene union all select 'Project Number' from vw_non_onco_cell_gene onco_cell_gene union all select 'Project Number' from vw_non_onco_pharma non_onco_pharma union all select 'Project Number' from vw_plasma_protein plasma_protein),
cte2 AS (SELECT 'Project Number', COUNT(*) cnt FROM cte1 GROUP BY 'Project Number'), cte3 AS (select 'Project Number', COUNT(*) cnt from vw_FCT_HTA_ONC_NONONC_PGMS GROUP BY 'Project Number'), cte4 AS (SELECT 'Project Number' FROM cte1 UNION  SELECT 'Project Number' FROM cte3) SELECT 'Project Number' FROM cte4 LEFT JOIN cte2 USING ('Project Number') LEFT JOIN cte4 USING ('Project Number') WHERE cte2.cnt IS NULL OR cte4.cnt IS NULL OR cte2.cnt <> cte4.cnt
"""

df = spark.sql(sql_query)
```

Comment: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`cte4.cnt`' given input columns: [cte4.Project Number, cte2.cnt]; line 2 pos 417;
'Project ['Project Number]

Comment: @Shivika that's a column in your query. I didn't invent anything. If you have this error it means that the column cnt doesn't exist in ct4. Fix your query